# C# MVC problem with file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make uploading a file to the server at my mvc project. I wrote my class,

```
public class MyModule: IHttpModule

which defines the event

void app_BeginRequest (object sender, EventArgs e)

In it, I check the length of the file that the user has selected to send.

if (context.Request.ContentLength> 4096000)
 {
  //What should I write here, that file is not loaded? I tried
   context.Response.Redirect ("address here");
  //but the file is still loaded and then going on Redirect.
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do -- check that the file doesn't exceed a maximum size? Also, I don't believe you need to create an implementation of IHttpModule to handle file upload -- you can simply use an [HttpPost] action in your controller that takes a HttpPostedFileBase parameter.

Answer (score 5):

In ASP.NET MVC you don't usually write http modules to handle file uploads. You write controllers and inside those controllers you write actions. Phil Haack [blogged](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) about uploading files ni ASP.NET MVC:

You have a view containing a form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("upload", "home", FormMethod.Post, 
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

    <input type="submit" />
<% } %>
```

And a controller action to handle the upload:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 4096000)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("FileTooBig");
        }
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: When triggered event Upload, file will already be uploaded to the server. If the file is larger than a certain value, I do not want to load it.

Comment: @darin I have used this code to save the file in the directory 
But I am receiving HttpPostedFileBase null in the controller

Comment: @user1006544, you must have forgot something and your code probably doesn't look exactly as the one shown here.

Comment: @darin I am showing you my code see this [Link](http://pastebin.com/y395fASK) 
I am receiving null in the fill

Comment: @user1006544, in the code you have shown your file input doesn't have a name! Look at my code once again.